# Full calendar: start calendar with a specific week

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm using Full Calendar, I have a starting date and I need the calendar starts the week that corresponds to this date , I need to hide the previous weeks. here is a picture that explains my question.
**in this example the starting date is April 20th.**
[image]

```js
$(".fc-day").each(function() {  
    var startDate = $('#start_date').val();

    if (($(this).data('date')) < startDate){
        $(this).parents().addClass('hidden');
    }

});
```

**I found a solution how to remove previous weeks, but I don't know how to replace them with future weeks.
This is the new script :**

```
$(".fc-day").each(function() {  

                startDate = $('#start_date').val();
                var date1 = new Date ($(this).data('date'));
                var date2 = new Date (startDate);
                var DD = date2.getDate();
                var MM = date2.getMonth() + 1;
                var YYYY = date2.getFullYear();
                var startTraining = YYYY + '-'+ MM + '-'+ DD;
                if ((date1 < date2) && (($(this).parent().get(0)) !== ($('.fc-day[data-date="' + startTraining + '"]').parent().get(0)))){
                    $(this).closest('.fc-row').addClass('hidden');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', startDate);

Comment: Yes, but it changes just the month, not the week

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar automatically renders the week the date is in according to the [`firstDay`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/firstDay/) property, so besides settings the correct day you also have to set the `firstDay` property to the correct day number by calling `getDay()`.

```
element.fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: startDate,
    firstDay: startDate.getDay()
});
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn, but I have to work with the month view.

Comment: I found a solution how to remove previous weeks, but I don't know how to replace them with future weeks